# Why is this line printing in CMD when I have told it to cls?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, ping

So I want it to not show that it is pinging, just whether or not it is running.
My code that is not doing what I want it to is:

```
@echo off
:start
ping 188.138.32.53 -n 1
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
goto :fail
) else (
cls
echo The MTG SAMP Server is up and running!
pause
goto :troubleshooting
)
:fail
cls
echo The MTG SAMP Server is currently down, please be patient...
goto :start
```

It clears the screen and only says when it is running, but when it is not running, it displays the ping status. Why is this?

Comment: just redirect the output of ping to nothing ie ping 10.1.1.1 > null

Comment: Thanks! This and jeb's answer both worked like a charm! Although it does take a minute for it to display the text, this should work! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are in a loop.

The ping needs some time to detect that the destination isn't reachable.
So you see this on the screen.

After the first test, the `cls` is executed and your text is displayed.
But as you startet the test again, you get also the ping output.

Simply redirect the output to `nul`

```
ping 188.138.32.53 -n 1 > nul 2>nul
```